# Why it is showing error ''Error: Expected a value of type Future but got one of type '-Dynamic'''

Tags: dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Error: Expected a value of type Future but got one of type '-Dynamic'
I don't know why it is showing this error I am new to flutter and
.plz any one here help me in solving it.. gskjbggchegegvfyuetvbyegflebgeicgbui;;ncbrgbgruibeurnuteehjkfkjfggfkjfgfjgj ff hco fco g fj gefgcefgecfgub

```
         This is my model page:

           // To parse this JSON data, do
          //
          //     final welcome = welcomeFromJson(jsonString);

       import 'dart:convert';

    Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

   class Welcome {
     Welcome({
    this.page,
    this.perPage,
    this.total,
    this.totalPages,
    this.data,
    this.support,
});

int? page;
int? perPage;
int? total;
int? totalPages;
List<Datum>? data;
Support? support;

factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
    page: json["page"],
    perPage: json["per_page"],
    total: json["total"],
    totalPages: json["total_pages"],
    data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    support: Support.fromJson(json["support"]),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "page": page,
    "per_page": perPage,
    "total": total,
    "total_pages": totalPages,
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "support": support!.toJson(),
};
}

 class Datum {
   Datum({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.avatar,
});

int? id;
String? email;
String? firstName;
String? lastName;
String? avatar;

factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    id: json["id"],
    email: json["email"],
    firstName: json["first_name"],
    lastName: json["last_name"],
    avatar: json["avatar"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "email": email,
    "first_name": firstName,
    "last_name": lastName,
    "avatar": avatar,
  };
  }

  class Support {
  Support({
    this.url,
    this.text,
  });

String? url;
String? text;

factory Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Support(
    url: json["url"],
    text: json["text"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "url": url,
    "text": text,
   };
 }
```

And this is my This is Profile controller page

```
      import 'package:api/model/profile.dart';
       import 'package:api/services/remoteservics.dart';
         import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:get/get.dart';

       class profilecontroller extends GetxController{

       late Future<Welcome> jsonModel;

    @override
  onInit() {
  jsonModel = profilecontroller().FechProfile();
  super.onInit();
  }


 FechProfile() async {
var profiles = await RemoteServics.FechProfile();
if(profiles!=null){
  // productList.value = profiles ;
  jsonModel= profilecontroller().FechProfile();

    }
   }
 }
```

And this is my services page :

```
 class RemoteServics{
  static var client =HttpClient();

 static Future <Map<String,dynamic>>  FechProfile() async{
 var jsonModel = null;
 var url = Uri.parse("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
 http.Response response = await http.get(url);
 var jsonstring = response.body;
// print(jsonstring);
// return Welcome.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
var jsonmap = json.decode(jsonstring);
// return [jsonstring].cast<Welcome>();
jsonModel = Welcome.fromJson(jsonmap);
return jsonModel;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You had not set the return type of your function:

```
Future<Welcome> FechProfile() async {
```

You may want to crank up your linter and compiler, this should be a compile time problem, it should never go to runtime.

---

That said... why isn't your compiler/linter throwing a fit here? I can see many more of those problems in your code. Make sure your compiler is up to speed, your flutter is updated and you listen to all warnings you get.